# Kendo mobile scrolling doesn't work when page includes iframe in it

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm using Kendo Mobile in my application and seems it has issue when page includes some iframe in it(youtube video in my case).
Scrolling works fine everywhere except when user taps on iframe during scrolling.

```
new kendo.mobile.Application();
```

Here is [***Jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/bYKYE/286/) example.

You can test issue with your mobile device(I've tested with iPhone 4) with [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/bYKYE/286/embedded/result/) link.

Comment: guys, please don't use latin alphabet

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should work - iframes are designed to swallow events on top of them - meaning that every touch on the iframe is handled by the page inside it and not the surrounding document. One possible solution could be that you place an overlay on top of the iframe thus catching all events above it and filter them manually (fire them yourself inside the iframe on the proper places).

Another possibility is to avoid using iframes at all.